# quotes in unix shell

Tags: shell

Trying to prepare simple shell commit script for git, like

```
git add .
git commit -m $@
git push origin master
```

to run it in ./script.sh 'commit message' manner
I ran into issue with commit messages containing space. I understand I need to wrap $@ in quotes on string 2, but all my tries have failed so far(I tried straight ', then \', then fancy '\'' I found while researching, still no luck). Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `$@` with `"$@"`. That should do the trick.

Comment: This might be a case where `"$*"` is a better choice. If `script.sh` doesn't need to take any other arguments, it frees the user from needing to quote the commit message when calling `script.sh`. All arguments would be combined into a single word for `-m`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the script as:

```
./script.sh 'commit message'
```

then the commit message is just `$1`, and your script should contain:

```
git commit -m "$1"
```